# error with Pnp PowerShell updating SharePoint look up column

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

i am trying to make my life easier and input less data into a sharepoint list, i have all items working except for the ""OneDriveUPNGroupDept" = $inputOneDriveUPNGroupDept;" is giving me the error below, any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
$CSVData = Import-CsV -Path $CSVFile
 
#Iterate through each Row in the CSV and import data to SharePoint Online List


ForEach ($Row in $CSVData)
{
# add note in window stating adding user

    Write-Host "Adding Item $($Row.'Asset Number')"

    #Add List Items - Map with Internal Names of the Fields!
    $inputupns = $($Row.'UPNS')
    $inoutOneDriveUPNSubmitter = $($Row.OneDriveUPNSubmitter)
    $inputOneDriveUPNGroupDept = $($Row.OneDriveUPNGroupDebt)
    $UnloadOneDrive = $($Row.UnloadOneDriveContentDate)
    $inputTcktNum = $($Row.oneDriveUPNTicketNbr)
    
    Add-PnPListItem -List $ListName  -Values @{
    
    "Title" = $inputupns;

    "OneDriveUPNSubmitter" = $inoutOneDriveUPNSubmitter;

    "OneDriveUPNEarliestUnloadDate" = $UnloadOneDrive;

    "OneDriveUPNTicketNbr" =  $inputTcktNum;
    "OneDriveUPNGroupDept" = $inputOneDriveUPNGroupDept; #is lookup field

    };
```

error: Add-PnPListItem : Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my look up value is not populating wit the information that i am inputting. if i copy paste the information it finds it but not populating when using PowerShell.

Comment: Your code snippet was poorly formatted, hence my comment. I've fixed it for you now.

Comment: It's unclear where `$ListName` comes from - it isn't defined in the code you've posted. If no such variable exists, you're effectively passing `$null`, which may explain the error.